# Are there official plans to remove the 100ml carry-on restriction in Europe?

Tags: airport-security, eu

I remember reading a few years ago that the EU is planning to remove the 100ml restriction for liquids. E.g. a [random article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-1269964/EU-airport-liquid-ban-hand-luggage-continue-2013.html) from 2010:

> The good news for air passengers? The end of a ban on carrying liquids through airport security is in sight. The bad news? The current restrictions are not likely to be lifted for another three years.
>
> The EU has announced that the laws will continue until 2013 when mass-screening technology to detect explosives in fluids is perfected.

Are there currently any plans to remove the restriction?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/what-are-the-exact-reasons-why-one-cannot-take-a-bottle-of-water-on-the-plane

Comment: [This European Commission website](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/aviation-security-policy/lags_en.htm) promises a Phase 1 by 2014.

Comment: I'm sure lots of people have 'plans' but are you looking for confirmed legislation?

Comment: @MarkMayo yes, something directly confirmed by the European Parliament or some other official structure. Likewise if the American FAA is planning to reverse the ban, that would be a good answer as well as it's likely that Europe will follow through

Comment: You can now take >100ml on Aussie domestic flights, is my understanding, just not if it's connecting to an international one.

Comment: Seems like at least in the meantime they could set up liquid dump and water refill stations... Such a PITA.

Comment: @pericynthion Pretty much all U.S. airports have drinking water fountains both before and after security. You can dump your water in the drain of one of them before security (or, as a last resort, in the trash cans in the screening lines) and then refill them from water fountains inside security. Many airports now have drinking water fountains specifically designed to refill water bottles.

Comment: @reirab Yes, but a lot of the time they're not conveniently located and usually require re-queuing for security if you forgot until you got there.  And it seems to be even worse in many European airports.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is not not reached a point yet where there is a proposed legislation.

The problem with liquid screening is highlighted in the Commission's latest [civil aviation security report](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A52015DC0360), published about a year ago:

> At the end of November 2014, the Commission received the results of an additional study assessing a possible second phase for lifting of the liquid restrictions. This study was carried out by the consultant ICF International. It assessed the possibility of permitting passengers to carry bottled water through a series of airport trials and also checked the findings of the previous study, in relation to the operational impact of the first phase. Also, this study concluded that the first phase had no negative operational impact on EU airports, even during the summer peak of operations at the EU airports involved in this study. It however also concluded that there may be a significant impact on throughput and cost for EU airports should the restrictions be further lifted to permit passengers to also carry bottled water. This is mainly due to the expected high number of bottles that would need to be screened and which would require significantly more liquids screening equipment. The outcome of this study led the Commission, in concertation with Member States, stakeholders and its international partners, to postpone the introduction of the second phase of lifting the liquid restrictions.

That being said, the issue is still being worked on. Trials are conducted at various airports to test the process. These are usually not publicly announced, with the exception of [this Malta Airport press release](https://www.maltairport.com/mia-chosen-european-commission-pilot-project-liquids-screening/) where trials were conducted in the last two months:

> Through this project Malta International Airport is contributing towards enhancing the passenger experience for travellers within the EU. The key participant airports for this project are Amsterdam Schiphol Airport, Budapest International Airport, Alicante International Airport, Dublin International Airport, and Malta International Airport.
>
> The airport team has already conducted some initial trials, to establish the ideal testing environment. With the technology and equipment now available for LAGs to be screened, MIA’s security team will be determining best practices for this new screening procedure whilst maintaining the requirements of the current EU legislation. The results from the participant airports will be analysed by the European Commission, with a view to implement new guidelines on LAGs.
>
> When this exercise is taking place, passengers who may, in special circumstances, be carrying LAGs of more than 100ml will be subjected to further screening.

O&I Consulting, the company which conducts these trials for the European Commission, currently carries out an [online survey](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/themes/passengers/consultations/2016-eu-air-travel-passenger-liquid-survey_en.htm) on that issue.

Comment: The survey is a great find! Filled it out and hoping for future improvements.