Why was I was allowed to bring 1.5 liters of liquid through security at Frankfurt Airport?
I had two liquid containers of 1 and 0.5 liters and thought I'd have to empty both of them before security. The guy there told me there were no restrictions on liquids and I could just bring them.
I've never experienced this in the EU before. As a matter of fact, I recall restrictions on liquids while flying from Munich just a few weeks ago.
Does Frankfurt have some special kind of machine that sniffs for explosives in the liquids or something? How do they get to allow the liquids, unlike other EU airports?

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/are-there-official-plans-to-remove-the-100ml-carry-on-restriction-in-europe

Out of curiosity, can I ask what made you chose the plane rather than the train to travel between Frankfurt and Munich?

Peripheral: Me on brief layby in Sydney Australia outbound to China from NZ.|| "You have been randomly selected for a voluntary explosives test" | 'What happens if I decide not to volunteer?' | Then, Sir, your journey stops here". | Well, I'd like to volunteer for the test.' || I was also explosives sniffed at the Tower of London and in China. I wonder what my profile shows ? :-)

@Russell McMahon What profile? Wow

Could this video be relevant? https://youtu.be/nyG8XAmtYeQ

@kiradotee yes, thank you!

Frankfurt airport, like several others in Germany, has "C3 standard Explosive Detection Systems for Cabin Baggage" scanners which currently exempts the airport from needing to enforce the 100ml rule. Unfortunately, the EU is going to reimpose this rule even on airports with these scanners from September 1st 2024.

Gotta love the EU forcing them, huh. Security theatre is so fun.

@Fiksdal It's more likely that EU is pressured by other countries that still insist on similar rules in order to keep EU security standards recognized.

@xngtng The decision seems to be down to technical concerns about the scanners performance. I can't find a proper explanation of exactly what the issue is though.

They probably don't want to publicize any details of performance issues on security equipment for reasons that should be obvious. From this document
"Such configuration could continue being operated in accordance
with the concept for operations for standard C3 EDSCB, but with a screening limit of the maximum volume of
individual LAG containers not to exceed 330 ml." Or they could just limit it to 100ml, of course.

I always felt the shops at the gates and the airlines got accustomed to selling their very expensive water, so they are against reverting to the state before the "show bombers". (In the beginning everybody had to take of the shoes, too. Taking off hiking boots can take some time, and nobody would put those in the suitcase...)

@U.Windl: We Americans mostly still have to take our shoes off, unless exempt by age or PreCheck.

AMS, Schiphol Amsterdam has machines where you can/could take full bottles of liquids through but it is announced that this will have to stop to be in step with other EU or Schengen airports.
I guess Frankfurt Airport also has the new machines to check the hand luggage and had not yet implemented the roll back, (if they are going to.)

So do those machines somehow pick up what liquids are?

This answer was posted as an answer as being too much for a comment and before the other answer was posted.
