# How did security checks at airports change after September 11th, 2001?

Tags: airport-security, event-based-effects, history

I’m quite young – young enough that I have never flown before the terrorist attack on the World Trade Center in New York.

I have doubts about the movie [United 93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_93_%28film%29): Was it possible to enter an airplane with a knife and/or a (fake) bomb? Was the hijacking possible due to some errors in the security system, or was the system simply not reliable enough to avoid a hijacking?

So, what security checks on passengers entering the restricted area changed after that event?

Comment: You folks can probably give a more comprehensive answer from a passenger perspective than most of us over at [aviation.SE] - and certainly a less snarky one than I could muster. [All I have to offer is this delightful song by a bunch of lawyers from Texas.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N86DiQZ7z8A) :-)

Comment: To help clarify, are you looking for changes in the passenger's experience only?  versus all the stuff that goes on in the IT world?

Comment: Is there a particular country you're interested in?  As I note below, the "before" security situations differed from country to country, as well as the "after" situations.

Comment: Also to clarify, what place(s) are you referring to? The changes are different depending on where you are. As might be expected (considering the attacks were in the U.S.,) the most pronounced differences that resulted from 9/11 are probably in the U.S.

Comment: I lived on a farm as a kid.  Carrying a pocketknife was completely normal.  I flew with one more than once and no one had a problem with it.  Then 9/11 happened.

Comment: I'm with @Mason on this. I used to dump my pocket knife in the little tray with my coins and keys. Every once in a while someone would measure the blade or check that it didn't lock before giving it back. In the US.

Comment: If that seems hard to believe to you already, what are you going to think when you hear about [the story of "Dan Cooper"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper)?

Comment: @chirlu especially parts like "...took seat 18C (...) in the rear of the passenger cabin. He lit a cigarette...."

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There were a bunch of changes to US airport security screening after 9/11. I'm not sure if there's a comprehensive list anywhere, but here are a few highlights:

### What Didn't Change

- **You still walk through a metal detector**
  Airlines generally don't want their passengers starting gun, knife, or chain fights on the airplane. For one thing you might damage the aircraft, and for another it's REALLY hard to get blood out of the seats and carpet.
  Also a survey of flight crews reveals that they overwhelmingly prefer not being shot or stabbed while working.
- **Your carry-on still gets X-rayed**
  The airlines want to know what's in your bag - they're not only concerned about weapons (see above) but also other dangerous or prohibited items.
  (Sorry, but [you can't take your pet crocodile on the plane](http://abcnews.go.com/Travel/plane-crashes-crocodile-escapes-panic/story?id=11947027) unless it's already been made into a crocodile-skin bag.
- **Your checked luggage is still subject to X-ray and/or hand inspection**
  See above for carry-ons. A survey of baggage handlers reveals that they prefer not to be bitten by crocodiles that escaped into the cargo hold.

---

### The Sensible Changes

- **[ID checks](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) are more stringent**
  It's been a *LONG* while since you could run up to the counter 10 minutes before departure and say "I need to be on that plane, print me a boarding pass! I'll pay in cash!" (that era predates *me*), but now the ID you present needs to match the name your ticket is under.
- **Only ticketed passengers are allowed into the secure area**
  As [Michael noted](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/53241/24437) this is standard practice in some other countries.
- **The "Explosive Trace Detection" machine gets used more**
  There are several models of this device, the most common use a swab or a "puff chamber" and a spectrometer to look for chemicals normally associated with explosives. These devices are pretty accurate and good at what they do, and because effectively cleaning explosives residue from clothing and equipment is non-trivial they're a nice tool in the screening arsenal.

  - There are "whole body" trace detectors that blow a column of air around a passenger to check for explosive traces, but I've not encountered one myself. I have however had a lot of technical equipment swabbed.
- **The baggage X-Rays are WAY better now**
  Many airports had older-generation X-Ray systems for examining carry-ons and checked baggage. These were single-density X-Ray systems with low-resolution sensors that produce a pretty poor image.
  I haven't seen one of those at an airport in years - the new systems are variable-density (they can deal with a mix of things inside your bag) and *much* higher resolution. I'm sure the old machines would eventually have all been retired and replaced, but the pace of adoption was probably accelerated.
- **"Random" enhanced screenings** (`SSSS`)
  Whether or not it's *truly* random, some portion of passengers receive ["Secondary Security Screening Selection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_Security_Screening_Selection) - an extra-thorough (and somewhat more time-consuming) screening process.
  Diverting some percentage of passengers through this process is theoretically an effective deterrent (though in practice if you're planning something nefarious and discover you've been selected for secondary screening there are several opportunities for you to abort your nefarious plan and avoid capture).

### The less-sensible changes

- **Your laptop probably can't stay in its bag**
  Unless you have a TSA-approved laptop bag you must remove your laptop from its carry-on bag and place it in an X-Ray Transparent bin for screening.
  This is "less sensible" as it's time-consuming, but there is logic behind it (radiopaque items in some laptop bags make it difficult to discern "normal laptop-looking bits" from "bomb-cleverly-disguised-as-a-laptop bits".
- **Backscatter X-Ray or Pat-Down of passengers**
  Perhaps the TSA's most controversial policy, frequently derided as "the nudie-scanner" and "freedom gropes", and plagued by stories of misses (where prohibited items made it through the checkpoint despite the supposedly-thorough screening elements).
  [As Nate points out](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53237/what-changed-between-before-and-after-09-11-2001-in-the-security-check-at-the/53246?noredirect=1#comment108984_53246) the backscatter x-ray devices have been largely (if not entirely) replaced with millimeter wave scanners - same concept, but theoretically lower risk (less ionizing radiation exposure) and possibly slightly better resolution.
  While I consider them to be largely security theater in the sense that they're not as good (cost, time, or detection rate) as the TSA would have us believe there is some merit to employing the techniques. Our indiscriminate and universal use of them is what lands them in my "less sensible" bin.

### The "Are you serious? This is pointless!" changes

- **Please remove your shoes**
  Yes, there was once a time when you didn't have to smell the feet of your fellow passengers. But then [some guy tried to light his shoe on fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Reid#Changes_in_airline_security_procedures) and that ruined it for everyone.
  This lands in the "Are you serious?" bin because not only is it protecting us from *yesterday's* threat, it is also full of loopholes: Children under 12 don't have to take their shoes off, nor do passengers who go through the "TSA Pre-Check" screening path (which is sometimes opened up to non Pre-Check passengers if the main screening path is backed up).
- **Sorry, no water bottles**
  More specifically, [some pretty draconian restrictions on "liquids"](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule). Where you used to be able to bring your coffee or water bottle purchased *outside* the secure area in with you, now you must abandon it and buy a new one inside the checkpoint.
  The water you bought *outside* the checkpoint was delivered on the same truck that delivered the water *inside* the checkpoint (probably by the same person), which makes the whole thing pretty silly. But even ignoring that, there are again loopholes here (like "infant nourishment").
  The overall effectiveness of this rule is highly debatable, but it *does* have the benefit of getting people to put their liquids in sealed baggies so if a container breaks or leaks it doesn't mess up anyone else's carry-on.

Comment: Note that a few of these changes are "Post-Post-9/11", like backscatter X-Ray of passengers and the "Please remove your shoes" routine, but I'm lumping them in under the larger heading of "9/11 induced security hysteria" around airports and air travel.

Comment: Good summary.  Note that the "no liquids" restrictions were also "post-post-9/11", as they were largely a reaction to the ["liquid explosive plot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_transatlantic_aircraft_plot) of 2006.

Comment: You might also add restrictions on sharp objects. Prior to 9/11 passengers were allowed to carry small pocket knives or (ahem) box cutters on the plane.

Comment: Also, I believe the reference to backscatter X-ray scanners is now obsolete, since I understand they have been replaced by millimeter wave scanners.

Comment: Also, you may or may not walk through a metal detector in the U.S. now. Sometimes you will be directed through the metal detector, other times you will be directed through the millimeter wave scanner. PreCheck is nice. It's almost like pre-9/11, except that you still can't go airside without a boarding pass and you still might have to go through the millimeter wave scanner.

Comment: Regarding the water bottles, interestingly, [there are some flights from some places the water you just bought/filled airside will be confiscated in the jetway as you board](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36557/12011).

Comment: @NateEldredge The sharp objects prohibition has always been there, it just wasn't really enforced as stringently. (Airlines never wanted passengers bringing box cutters on the plane, but the relatively small amount of metal in them would not *normally* trip the metal detector alarms.) You're right about the millimeter-wave scanners though: New technology, same idea (and many of the same flaws/blind spots sadly)

Comment: @reirab I haven't been through an airport that didn't still have metal detectors yet - I'd be deeply concerned if they're removing them though, it's one of the few *proven effective* screening tools in the arsenal.

Comment: @voretaq7 I think all of the airports I've been through _had_ metal detectors, but you normally don't actually pass through them if they direct you through one of the body scanners. It's usually one or the other, not both. As far as sharp objects, not only the enforcement, but the rules themselves also used to be a lot more lax. Small knives were allowed (as they still are in most countries.) Even TSA agrees that having the ban on small knives actually _reduces_ security, but the flight attendants' union complained when they tried to start allowing them again.

Comment: @voretaq7: I'm with reirab: I'm pretty sure the rules actually used to be more permissive.  Pre-9/11, I used to carry a Swiss Army knife with me everywhere, and I have pretty clear memories of bringing it on planes (putting it in the bin to go through the metal detector; nobody objected).  I think I used it to open bags of peanuts.  I have a recollection of a 3-inch blade length limit, and the Swiss Army knife had maybe a 2.5 inch blade.

Comment: @voretaq7 Small blades **were** permissible.  One time at security they noticed a blade (pocket knife) the person in front of me was carrying.  They measured it, it was under 3", they were allowed on the plane with it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, things like a swiss army knife (keychain or pocket) used to be permitted, multitools would usually be fine too, as well as nail clippers (what am I going to do, *groom the flight attendant to death*?). A lot of what people complain about today wouldn't get through back then either though: folding knives, most box cutters if security saw them, etc. There were some "dumb" prohibitions enforced pre-9/11 too (soldering stations, stub screwdrivers, etc.) that I'd been bitten by more than once, but it wasn't consistent. Now the policy is tighter and more strictly enforced.

Comment: Famous computer security researcher Bruce Schneier calls this "Security theater"

Comment: "These devices are pretty accurate".  Depends on your definition of accurate.  They might have very few false negatives, but I've seen a lot of false positives.  To me "accurate" would mean that at least 25% of the times it triggers are not false alarms.

Comment: @PatrickM The problem is that the systems will encounter literally millions of actual negatives per actual positive. Getting such a small ratio of false positives to true positives would be nearly impossible under those circumstances.

Comment: @reirab I get that this test isn't fair.  I just wanted to point out that there are a lot of things which set them off that don't explode.  A friend of mine has to make sure not to use the handsoap at his work, because using it on the day he leaves will set off the detectors.

Comment: Can you give an example of a radiopaque part of  laptop bag?

Comment: @nitro2k01 Anything metal is likely radiopaque (at least partially - enough that it makes it hard to get a good scan of the laptop). That's actually only one of the requirements for a "checkpoint-friendly" laptop bag, though its the one that affects my personal preferred bag (which has metal zippers). [The TSA gives more information here](https://www.tsa.gov/news/releases/2008/08/15/checkpoint-friendly-laptop-bag-procedures).

Comment: @PatrickM While the false-positive rate is pretty high viewed as a raw number it's actually pretty low as a percentage of scans (<1% is cited in a few mass spectrometry books). There *are* several well-known false-positive cases (certain glycerin-based cosmetics and soaps, some formulations of cardiac nitroglycerin), but adjusting the devices to rule those out often creates unacceptable false negatives, so as with all things in security it's a trade-off: A low-percentage but large number of time-consuming hand checks, or a greater chance of a "miss" & bombs getting onboard.

Comment: Don't forget the assumption by the government of responsibility for these checks.  Before the TSA was created, gate security was enforced by private companies.  I flew out of Logan in August 2001, and the guy monitoring the baggage scanner was literally falling asleep on the job.  I'll always regret the fact that I didn't say anything to anyone about it.  Ive certainly never seen anything like that since.

Comment: Actually, ID requirements have absolutely nothing to do with security, so I'd put them in the non-sensible category.

Answer (score 15):

In US airports, the biggest change from a "civilian's" perspective was probably the fact that only ticketed passengers are now allowed in the secure area.  Before 9/11, anyone could go through the security checkpoint and into the gate areas.  You might see this in older movies, with people greeting passengers right as they get off the jetway instead of coming through opaque doors into some arrivals hall.

Note that not all countries allowed people without tickets into the secure area before 9/11;  for example, I'm pretty sure that Canada only allowed ticketed passengers past security.  In such countries, this would not have been the biggest change.

Comment: This changed long before 2001, at least in some airports.  I was refused access to the gate as a non-traveler, to accompany my girlfriend, who was traveling, in 1994 or 1995.

Comment: @phoog At most U.S. airports, non-passengers were allowed to go through security prior to 9/11. I did so many times myself during the 90s.

Answer (score 5):

Overall, I think changes in Europe (which had prior experiences with international terrorism) were limited at first. What happened is that norms and procedures for US domestic flights were brought in line with those of other countries.

In the US changes included the access restrictions mentioned by Michael, stricter ID requirements, the [creation of the TSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_Security_Administration) and of the [No Fly List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Fly_List), and a ramping up of the [Federal Air Marshal Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Air_Marshal_Service).

Further changes were introduced later, like [Advance Passenger Information Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System) (useful to enforce no-fly lists and for screening programmes), the ban on liquids and gels and new scanning devices.

Answer (score 4):

> What changed after that event in the passenger security check, before
>   entering in the restricted area?

Virtually nothing changed. You were still asked the 3 key questions you are asked today, Did you pack the bag? Has the bag been out of your direct awareness since you packed it? Did you pack anything you shouldn't have?

The difference is that whereas before if you said no or I dont know to any of the above questions, they went through your bag. Now, regardless of what is said, they will probably cut your locks and go through your bag.

Since 9-11, a lot more of your stuff gets stolen before the bag makes it to the plane, and there is nothing you can do about it.

> Could be possible now to enter in an airplane with a knife and/or a
>   (fake) bomb?

Yes, there are actually a bunch of people that have done this over and over just to make a mockery of the TSA.

Before 9-11, you walked through a metal detector, and then you waited. If you set off the metal detector, you might get patted down.

Now, you have to take off your belt and shoes, you have random odds of "enhanced pat downs" based on "random number generators". If youre super lucky, the TSA takes you to their special hidden room for an enhanced security check (Sky Harbor has a doorless underground room for this.)

It's a whole crap ton of hassle and privacy invasion, but you can still hide a knife bundled in something in your bag, and the xray scanner wont get it. Even with the full body scanners, ANYTHING can be hidden in a fat roll.

All that hassle, no real gain.

> Was the hijacking possible for some errors in the security system, or it >simply wasn't reliable enough to avoid a hijacking?

It wasn't an "error in the system". Stop war. Stop murder. Stop violence. You can't. People have tried since the dawn of man, and there is just no way to stop it.

The TSA is an act of paranoia. Those who are hyper paranoid and afraid of the world enjoy the inconvenience because they feel like they are trading freedom for security. In reality, they are trading freedom for a placebo.

We are no better off in the airport than we were pre 9-11, it just takes 5 times as long to get through the airport, and it is now an often humiliating and angering experience.

Answer (score 3):

> Was it possible to enter an airplane with a knife and/or a (fake) bomb?

[Before 9/11 the US allowed blades less than four inches long](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/boxcutters-werent-allowed-pre-9-11/) as well as knitting needles, glass bottles and other sharp objects.

When you went through the metal detector you'd either leave it in your carry on or put it in a dish.  Security would often have a ruler or mark on the side of a table to check the blade against.

You would not be allowed on with a bomb if they caught you.  The security systems were far less able to detect bombs then, no fancy chemical detection machines.  Checked and carry on luggage was X-rayed.  Trained dogs could sniff out some types of explosives.  Luggage and carry-ons would be randomly searched by hand.

If your carry-on contained a lot of wires or electronics under the X-Ray, for example a laptop and charging cables (relatively rare in 2000), it might be searched.  You might be asked to turn the computer on to demonstrate it's not a fake.

> Was the hijacking possible due to some errors in the security system, or was the system simply not reliable enough to avoid a hijacking?

The system was looking for means to take over or destroy the plane.  It did not consider you could do that with box cutters and small knives.  It was looking for guns and bombs.  Rather than defeat security head-on, the hijackers exploited one of its assumptions.

The 9/11 attackers got away with it, in part, because [before 9/11 hijackers were not there to destroy the plane, they were there to take hostages and make demands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_hijacking#Dealing_with_hijackings).  In a hostage situation you'd cooperate and let the authorities handle it.  The 9/11 passengers did not realize they were in immediate danger.

It's my opinion that if there were another attempt to hijack an American plane 9/11 style, the hijackers would be overpowered by the passengers.  Better to die trying than die when they drive the plane into a building.

Comment: This is not universally true. Before 9/11 European airports certainly didn't allow knives with blades less than 4 inches long, though I was surprised and rather shocked when I found US airports didn't seem to care about them.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You're right; I will qualify this as being for the US.

Comment: After a wedding in the US, with my kilt, somehow my sgian dubh ended up in my hand luggage. (It's a knife, and a traditional part of the outfit). Raleigh-Durham didn't care; neither did Chicago or Minneapolis, but from Schiphol to Glasgow it had to be placed in an envelope and stowed in the hold. A very polite man with an MP5 said so...

Comment: Relatively rare?  I, as an impecunious music student, bought a laptop in 1999.  They can't have been *that* rare.  Certainly nobody looked at me strangely when I took it through security.  Also, one factor in 9/11 was the poor quality of the security staff in Logan.  I flew through there in August 2001, and the bag screener was literally falling asleep while he was trying to observe the x-ray machine's video monitor.  I thought about reporting it, decided not to, and have regretted that decision ever since the following month.

Answer (score 2):

In May 2001 I was able to greet visitors at the jetway in New York's La Guardia Airport. The rule at the time was ticketed passengers only, but the enforcement was obviously nothing like it is now. No one was matching IDs against boarding passes. Inspection of the passes was often cursory at best, and sometimes didn't occur at all. But the long TSA screening lines we know so well were only months away.

Comment: You still can greet visitors at the jetway.  You just have to buy a ticket within a 24 hour span of their arrival.  The new security procedures filter out terrorists who can not afford to buy an extra ticket.

Comment: @emory While that's amusing, and I had to think about it for a moment, the new procedures are more about being able to better control who is inside security. Buying a ticket means an extra layer of security checks. But that just means you need [a copy of Photoshop and a decent printer](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/07/man_flies_with.html). The TSA hopes if they put enough leaky security layers up you'll screw up and get caught by one.

Comment: @Schern You are correct.  I was just noting that if you have disposable cash, you can still do whatever you want to do.  I have noticed that some airports have special security lines for first class passengers - which remarkably are shorter than the coach class lines.  If I was organizing a 9/11 sequel, my team would be flying first class.

Comment: @emory it puts them closer to the cockpit, too.

Comment: @emory As I recall, the 9/11 terrorists actually flew first class, presumably for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Some other changes not mentioned here, but can be noticed:

1. Cockpit doors are reinforced and entry during flights is forbidden (prior to 9/11 it was restricted, but was allowed).
2. You cannot park near the airport terminal at most international terminals.
3. Your electronic devices need to power up if you are traveling to the US and UK. This means, if your battery is dead on your mobile, you will not be allowed to take it on board (this is a new regulation, which I noticed on my recent trip); here is the [relevant text](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items):

> Flying to and from the UK
>
> Make sure your electronic devices are charged before you travel. If
>   your device doesn’t switch on when requested, you won’t be allowed to
>   take it onto the aircraft.

The [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-28223150) covered this in more detail.

Comment: I'm not sure about #3. I've never been allowed to store lithium batteries in _check-in_ baggage, but I've had no issue carrying devices with them (with no indication whatsoever about how much battery was left) or carrying an extra one on my flights to/from the US.

Comment: As I mentioned, its a new regulation (July 2015).

Comment: I have flown between the Netherlands and the UK several times since July 2015 with phones and laptops and have never been asked nor seen others being asked to power up.