# Qatar Airways - 1 litre empty stainless steel water bottle through the security checkpoint

Tags: luggage, airport-security, regulations, qatar-airways

Is a 1 liter ***empty stainless steel*** water bottle allowed to be carried through the security checkpoint?

I've just read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9754/53670) (and gave a look at the answers) which is only about plastic. The word *metal* does not appear on the page, nor *stain* or *steel* do.

My travel is ***Pisa(Italy)-Doha-Singapore*** (and then vice-versa) operated by ***Qatar Airways***.

The bottle in question is very very important to me, also because it is very very expensive. The reason I'd like to carry it with me in the cabin is that I don't want it to be "harmed" during baggage load and/or unload.

Comment: Generally speaking, I try not to take things that are *very very important to me* while traveling and instead leave them home or in someone's care where I know they'll be safe and not get misplaced, mishandled, or potentially confiscated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The material doesn't matter. Neither does the airline.

Empty canisters are fine. The regulations are about liquids not things that might or might not hold a liquid. Make sure it's *empty*. Wipe it. A vindictive security person might try to mess with you otherwise.

Comment: when you write that _The material doesn't matter. Neither does the airline._, are you talking about regulation about liquids only or about regulations in general?

Comment: I'm not sure that material doesn't matter. A metal container could be construed as a harmful object by an overzealous security agent.

Comment: I once tried to travel from Israel to Europe with a double wall hot water boiler. Since the border agents couldn't see between the walls, they had to dismember it, until they were convinced it was safe. At the end I left it there, since they completely destroyed it.

Answer (score 2):

Security checkpoints aren't run by the airlines: it's national regulations that matter, not any airline's rules.

I have never had any problem taking an empty metal water bottle through the security checkpoint at any airport I've been to (Europe, including Italy, US, Canada, Japan). Sometimes they ask if there's anything in it. Once, it was swabbed.

However, you may have problems if the bottle is insulated: I've seen signs at airports (can't remember where, sorry) saying that vacuum flasks can't be taken through security, presumably because the screeners can't tell if you've secreted something in the insulation cavity.

However, as mentioned in the comments, it's better to leave at home anything that you can't afford to lose while travelling.