# Question about water bottles

Tags: air-travel, airports, airlines, airport-security

I was wondering if i'm allowed to bring a water jug on the airlines. The size of it is 74.4 ounces and 2.2 liters. The brand is Arrow home products. It would also be brought empty with nothing inside it. I would be riding either Delta or American Airlines to Houston,TX from Columbia,SC.

Comment: There was a similar question in the past https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/can-you-bring-an-empty-water-bottle-with-you-on-the-plane?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/empty-water-bottle an empty water bottle is permitted in both carry on and checked luggage. There is no mention of any size restriction.

(Note: there’s no match when searching ‘water jug’ on the TSA site)